# Effective use of stack vs. heap memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am developing a large, complex model (mostly simple math, primarily algebra, but lots of calculations).  I did my initial bid assuming I'd have to do everything once, but now the scope has expanded such that I need to run the entire model multiple times (on the same set of underlying assumptions but with a different dataset).

Based on my initial needs, I created a bunch of classes, then created dynamic instances of those classes in my main function, passing them by reference to each function as I went.  That way, at the end of the main function, I can do all the necessary reporting / output once all of the functions have run.  My question is about how to now modify my main function to allow for multiple iterations.  A few sample bits of code below, followed by my question(s):

```
 // Sample class declaration (in main)
 vector<PropLevelFinancials> PLF;

// Sample function call (functions in other header files)
ProcessPropFinancials(vector<PropLevelFinancials>& PLF);

// Reporting at the end of main (functions in other header files)
OutputSummaryReport(vector<PropLevelFinancials>& PLF, other objects);

// What I need to do next
// Clear/Delete PLF and other objects, iterate through model again
```

I am quite happy with the speed and result of my current program, so don't need a whole lot of input on that front (although always welcome suggestions).

How should I implement the ability to cycle through multiple datasets (I obviously know how to do the loop, my question is about memory management)?  Speed is critical.  I want to essentially delete the existing instance of the class object I have created (PLF), and then run everything again on a new instance of the object(s).  Is this the type of situation where I should use "new" and "delete" to manage the iterations?  Would that change my function calls as outlined above?  If I wanted to avoid using new and delete (stay on the stack), what are my options?

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, the only way to provide a definitive answer is to test and measure, although common sense would suggest that not allocating memory repeatedly will be better than allocating memory repeatedly.

Comment: "dynamic (stack) memory allocation" - huh nope. "dynamic" is the synonym for "memory allocated by `new`". "stack"-allocated objects are not considered "dynamic", at least as far as the not-so-standard generally used terminology is concerned.

Comment: If you want speed, then depending on the size of the PLF, you might not want to delete it, but reuse it.

Comment: @brentf **NOTE** that vector might use `new` under the hood when it comes to need for resizing the allocated memory for the instances kept. You might want to use `reserve()` or specify the expected number of objects to be held in the constructor. Doing this in the initialization phase of your program might prevent performance debts when filling the vector during processing.

Comment: @H2CO3 thank you for correcting my erroneous use of terminology, but if you're going to sharpshoot at least answer my question in the process.

Comment: @g-makulik I have been resizing the vectors using resize when I know how large I need them to be - does this sound like a good way of doing it (and maybe reserving space upfront since I generally know the magnitude of the potential vector sizes)?

Comment: @brentf Yes, sounds good to do so, for sake of avoiding performance hits during the processing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Do not, ever, use `new` and `delete` without a *highly* exceptional cause.

`std::vector<T>` offers a `clear()` member you can use. I suggest you implement a similar one for your own classes if that is what you need. Or you can simply do `PLF = std::vector<T>();`, which would work a bit better for your own UDTs without modification, assuming that you wrote them according to the most basic C++ guidelines.

Comment: "highly" might be a wee bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: @NikBougalis If you know enough C++ to justify using `new` and `delete`, you probably know enough C++ to not use `new` and `delete`.  The most common exception to this rule I can think of is "it is old code that I cannot fix because there are megabytes of it".

Comment: @Yakk Some of the STL classes encapsulate the use of `new` and `delete` internally, and usually it will be the best choice to use these. Nevertheless you should know when these do so and why, to avoid unexpected performance hits with algos critical about this.

Comment: @Nik: If you know enough C++ to actually find a justifying case, you will know virtually all there is to know on the topic and there would be little reason to seek my advice on such a matter.

Comment: @g-makulik Why yes, use code that uses `new` and `delete` plenty!  Just don't use it *directly*, with one of the exceptions being when you are writing code whose purpose is to encapsulate `new` and `delete` yourself.  Sprinkle `std::vector` hither and yon all you want!